# Pycharm, Django & PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, pycharm, psycopg2

Ok I know there are multiple questions on this topic but none of the answers seem to help. I am new to pycharm wanted to create a new django project with a postgresql backend, when I try to sync my db though I am having the dreaded psycopg2 module not valid Win32 app. However I have installed the Win32 version.

I am using Windows 7, python 2.7, postgresql 9.4, pycharm 4.5.3

I installed psycopg2-2.6.1.win32-py2.7-pg9.4.4-release.exe from stickpeople.com 
I also installed this in my virtual environment using easy_install psycopg2-2.6.1.win32-py2.7-pg9.4.4-release.exe

(if I could include images in the question I would show you a screen shot that states psycopg2 requirement is already satisfied when I try doing pip and or/easy install again for psycopg2 in the virtual environment)

The weird thing is when I installed the 32 version it displayed amd 64 is that correct?

When I run the command python manage.py syncdb though I get 'Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Here is my db settings in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'partguider',
    'USERNAME': 'admin',
    'PASSWORD': 'RArchie009',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '5432'
```

Anyone have an idea why the psycopg2 is not being recognized when I try syncing the DB? Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: you dont have psycopg2 in your installation dir

Comment: What installation directory? Python? I am showing in python27 directory psycopg2 is there?

Comment: @AjayGupta Hi Ajay what directory?

Comment: have you installed psycopg2?

Comment: Yes psycopg2 is installed, as I mentioned I used stickpeople.com site. I double clicked to install on my PC, also navigated to virtual environment dir, activated the virtual environment and did an easy_install of the psycopg2 again from stickpeople.com. (I have another virtenvir for a different project and that works fine but this one does not)

Comment: @AjayGupta sorry forgot to tag the above comment to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out. As my question states, in the error message it kept saying I had amd64 of psycopg installed even though I installed the win32 version from stickpeople.com..... So why then was the 64bit version installed, because of the pip cache. I accidentally installed the 64bit version first, I then uninstalled it and tried installing the correct 32 version but for some reason the cache kept installing the 64 bit version. I cleared cache, uninstalled any trace of the 64 bit version and installed the correct 32 bit version. Finally works...